# why in can't activate SCAYT functonnality

Tags: ckeditor4.x

*Hi everybody i have a probleme with scayt plugin for ckeditor 4 when i enable the scayt check speller the button appaer but i can active the functonality for check spelling i am on IE 11.0.9600.19080.
that my conf in config.js :

```
config.allowedContent = true; //Allow all content
   config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false; //Enable native spell checking      (browser)
    config.scayt_autoStartup = true; // Enable SCAYT on editor startup
    config.scayt_sLang = 'fr_FR';
    config.extraPlugins = 'scayt';
    config.toolbar =
        [
            [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ]]
```

Thanks for reply*

Answer (score 0):

You can start from simple demo and add all additional options step by step if you need.

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [{
    name: 'editing',
    items: ['Scayt', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline']
}];

CKEDITOR.replace('container', {
    scayt_autoStartup: true,
    grayt_autoStartup: true
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jalners/j4ytgb2v/